# How laravel match routes precedence

Tags: php, laravel

Case 1: `web.php`:

```
Route::get('foo/{id}', function () {
    return 'Route 1';
});
Route::get('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Route 2';
});
Route::get('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Route 3';
});
```

When I browse to `localhost/foo/bar` I got `Route 1` which correct since the url match the first route.

Case 2: `web.php`:

```
Route::post('foo/{id}', function () {
    return 'Route 1';
});
Route::get('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Route 2';
});
Route::get('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Route 3';
});
```

When I browse to `localhost/foo/bar` I got `Route 3`.

My question is why i got `Route 3` intead of `Route 2`. Isn't logical to get `Route 2` since the url match the second route first?! Why does Laravel continue to match the routes after match is found (route 2 in my case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `foo/bar` route overrides the first, because the HTTP Method and URI are the same.

The HTTP Method + URI combo acts as a primary key for a route. The combination of the two have to be unique - you can't have two different destinations for the same route.

So, Laravel takes a "last in, first out" approach, where any previous definition (e.g. "Route 2") is overwritten. You can confirm this by running `php artisan route:list` in the command line to see what route definitions Laravel will actually attempt to match.

Answer (score 0):

In *case 1*, **Route 1 has priority** because it has generated route (`foo/{id}`)

In *case 2*, Route 1 has priority **when you use post method** otherwise last route has priority which is route 3.